# Why are pseudo-elements selectable in Chrome, except for the last one, when using CSS counter() function?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

### CONTEXT:

`Pseudo-elements` are not supposed to be selectable since they are CSS generated content, which is not inserted into the DOM.

---

### QUESTION:

The question is:

Why are `pseudo-elements` selectable in Chrome, except for the last one, when using CSS `counter()` function in the `content` property?

---

### ILLUSTRATION:

[image: pseudo-elements bug Chrome]

---

### CODE SNIPPET:

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/1gx6bn1a/)**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  counter-reset: list-items;
}
li {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  counter-increment: list-items;
}
li:first-child {
  background-color: forestgreen;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: saddlebrown;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: firebrick;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
li::before {
  font-size: 10vw;
  content: counter(list-items, upper-alpha);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>
```

---

**NOTES:**

*Reproduced in Chrome Versión 53.0.2785.143 m (64-bit) / Windows 10.*

- This does not happen in FF nor Edge.
- Can be solved using the prefixed property `-webkit-user-select: none;` in pseudo-element.
- Flexbox has nothing to do with the issue, it used in the demo for illustration purposes.

Comment: Chrome 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit) in osx 10.11.6. No selectable. May be os the issue?)

Comment: Reproducible on Chromium version 53.0.2785.143 Built on 8.6, running on Debian 8.6 (64-bit). Smacks like a bug, even though IE11 on Windows 8.1 acts the same.

Comment: Oh, in Chromium, Ctrl+A does the same: it selects the A and the B, but not the C. IE11 selects all three letters with Ctrl+A. Mozilla selects nothing.

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic on Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. From where I see it, the only way to get a *proper* answer for your question would be to ask someone on Chrome development team. Anyone else would be just wild-guessing.

Comment: It's definitely something about the browser. Chrome selects just the first two (even with CTRL + A), Firefox doesn't select any (even with CTRL + A), Safari doesn't select any with CTRL + A but does select them on mouse drag, one at a time, and only the first two. So every browser handles it differently

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Because of two reasons: `1.` only the last child is affected. `2.` the problem does not occur when using other text as `content` -- in this case nothing is selectable. You can [submit](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en) this as an issue, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no negative space around. If you add some space around you can achieve the desired effect [jsfiddle with the solution](https://jsfiddle.net/1gx6bn1a/1/).

In real life it's the equivalent of grabbing a big box from the floor with one hand. It's easier to pull-it off if there is a bit of space for your hand in between the floor and the box.

```
ul {
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 90vh;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  counter-reset: list-items;
}
```